# How to create a hotkey for opening a new iTerm2 window?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, iterm, karabiner

I typically have multiple terminal sessions across different screens. Since opening the terminal is such a frequent task, I have a hotkey bound to `open -b com.googlecode.iterm2 .` with Karabiner-Elements. This way I can open a terminal from anywhere with one keypress.

Unfortunately if a terminal window is already open, this hotkey does not create a new window, but creates a new tab in existing windows. The existing window is often some long running "background" process like `top` or `watch`, meant to run undisturbed on a secondary screen while I do my work on the main screen. When a new tab is created in it, this causes problems for my workflow:

- Hides the monitoring session, which I probably want to see
- Opens the new terminal on the secondary screen, even if I had been working on the primary one
- Moving the terminal to my main screen also moves the monitoring session to the main screen, so I have to move it back when done
- Separating the tab requires finicky and tedious mouse dragging

These may seem like minor complaints, but I develop software and have to go in and out of terminals *a lot*. Depending on what I'm working on, I may need to open and close new terminals every few minutes, sometimes multiple times a minute. Reusing the same terminal is not really an option because often the terminals have distinct sessions (eg. TUI programs that run continuously, SSH to multiple different machines).

Is there a command I can bind that also creates a new `iTerm2` window?

In theory I could command-tab to the terminal first and use a hotkey to make a new window. This has 2 problems:

- Instead of one key press, I need to make several key presses to switch windows first.
- Doesn't handle edge case where terminal is not running already.

Comment: Spaces is not designed to handle a single app across more than one Space/Desktop. That's going to be your major hurdle, though idk specifically about iTerm.

Comment: @Tetsujin If I go to the Dock, right click the iTerm2 icon, and select "New Window", it creates a new window on the correct screen as I would expect. The problem is that this requires me to use the mouse, so I was hoping there's a command that does it.

Answer (score 3):

This is already built into iTerm2.  See the [Hotkeys](https://iterm2.com/documentation-hotkey.html) section in their documentation.

- Show/hide all windows with a dedicated, system-wide hotkey
- Create a dedicated hotkey window.

  > In its simplest form, it's a system-wide terminal window that you can open with a hotkey.

You can find these options in *Preferences -> Keys*

[OSXDaily](https://osxdaily.com/2018/03/14/instant-command-line-anywhere-mac-iterm2/) has an excellent write up on this (with pictures)

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for. This hotkey, while global, is assigned to a single terminal. If you press it repeatedly it will open and close a single terminal, not open new terminal windows.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to tell iTerm2 what to do through AppleScript. You can bind keys in Karabiner Elements to call the shell command `osascript` to accomplish this.

Example iterm2.json for this, using command-3 to open a new iTerm2 window using the default profile:

```
{
"title": "New iTerm2 Window",
"author": "Ahnberg <ahnberg@netnod.se>",
"rules": [ {
        "description": "New iTerm2 Window",
        "manipulators": [ {
                "type": "basic",
                "from": { "key_code": "3",
                          "modifiers": { "mandatory": [ "command" ] } },
                "to": [ { "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"iTerm\" to create window with default profile'" } ]
            } ]
    } ]
}
```

Put the json file in `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/` and then add it by going into Karabiner Elements preferences, selecting the "Complex Modifications" tab and clicking "+ Add Rule" in the bottom, and finally selecting "+ Enable" next to the rule.

Note: AppleScript support for iTerm2 is currently in maintenance mode and might be removed in the future. They currently recommend using the [Python API](https://iterm2.com/python-api/).

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems not to be a proper solution, you can try to use the drop-down terminal provided by iTerm in the Preferences->Keys->Hotkeys setting to create a hotkey window.